# reading multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need some help reading the values from multidimension arrays. The array looks like below.

```
Array
(
    [translations] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [translatedText] => fantasma
                    [detectedSourceLanguage] => en
                )
        )
)
```

I tried the following, but kept on getting blanks. Any help be appreciated?

```
foreach($item as $translations)
{
       foreach($row['0'] as $k)
       {
             echo $k['translatedText'];
             echo $k['detectedSourceLanguage'];
       }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$row` come from?

Answer (score 2):

When working with foreach loops, you want to call the array you plan on iterating over with the following syntax:

```
foreach($array as $variable){  }
```

Array being the array you plan on going through, and the variable being the variable you are planning to call it as within the foreach.

More information on foreach loops can be found at [PHP:foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

With that said, try the code below:

```
$data = array(
    "translations" => array(
        array("translatedText" => "fantasma", 
              "detectedSourceLanguage" => "en"
        )
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($data["translations"] as $translation) {
    echo $translation['translatedText'] . "<br />";
    echo $translation['detectedSourceLanguage'] . "<br />";
}

//Or, if the $data variable will be holding multiple translation arrays:

foreach($data as $d) {
    foreach($d as $translation){
        echo $translation['translatedText'];
        echo $translation['detectedSourceLanguage'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($item['translations'] as $translation) {
  echo $translation['translatedText'];
  echo $translation['detectedSourceLanguage'];
}
```

See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/F1QCg2)

Comment: Could you explain what you're expecting to be printed, and how this is different?

Comment: It would help if you showed more than just one element of the array, so I could tell precisely which parts you want to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below :

```
$test = Array(
    "translations" => Array (
        "0" => Array (
            "translatedText" => "fantasma",
            "detectedSourceLanguage" => "en"
        )
    )
);

foreach ($test as $translations) {
    foreach ($translations as $k) {
        echo $k["translatedText"];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $k["detectedSourceLanguage"];
    } 
}
```

This should work.

Follow this for more info about array : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: you sir are a genius! XOXOXO

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are not defining the `$row` variable.  The good news is that you don't need it.

You can simply do this:

```
foreach($item as $translations => $values)
{
       foreach($values as $k)
       {
             echo $k['translatedText']."\n";
             echo $k['detectedSourceLanguage'];
       }
}
```